# gdb cannot access c_str() function of std::string in boolean expression

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a file named testing.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    foo->name = "hello";

    std::cout << foo->name << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it to a.out, and start gdb using `gdb a.out`.

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.10-1.1) 7.10
...
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb)
```

I break at line 12 (`std::cout << foo->name << "\n";)`, and run:

```
(gdb) break 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400990: file testing.cpp, line 12.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ...

Breakpoint 1, main () at testing.cpp:12
12          std::cout << foo->name << "\n";
(gdb)
```

It can print `foo->name` and `foo->name.c_str()`:

```
(gdb) print foo->name
$1 = "hello"
(gdb) print foo->name.c_str()
$2 = 0x613c30 "hello"
```

It can print boolean expression with `foo->name.c_str()` in the first clause:

```
(gdb) print foo->name.c_str() && 1
$3 = true
```

But it can't when I put `foo->name.c_str()` in second clause:

```
(gdb) print 1 && foo->name.c_str()
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
(gdb)
```

Is this a bug?

---

Edit 1:

## Use Case

I was trying to use `break ... if ...` to break at some point if some strings have certain values. E.g.

```
(gdb) break 14 if foo->name.size() == 5 && $_streq(foo->name.c_str(), "house")
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400aba: file testing.cpp, line 14
(gdb)
```

When I `continue`, gdb show the error message and break at line 14 (`return 0;`) even though `foo->name` is "hello" but not "house".

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
hello
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.

Breakpoint 2, main () at testing.cpp:14
14          return 0;
(gdb)
```

Currently a workaround is access data member of `std::string` directly:

```
(gdb) break 14 if foo->name.size() == 5 && \
                  $_streq(foo->name._M_dataplus._M_p, "house")
```

## Some Observations

Is it because my `foo` is pointer?

Nope. I tried to use `Foo foo;` instead of `Foo* foo = new Foo;`. Problem remains.

Does this problem apply for `std::string` variable created in `main()`, oppose to as a data member of some object?

Nope. Seems like it only applies for `std::string` as a data member. Code below works:

```
(gdb) list 4,8
4       int main() {
5           std::string name("hello");
6           std::cout << name << "\n";
7           return 0;
8       }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400a93: file testing.cpp, line 6
(gdb) run
Starting program: ...

Breakpoint 1, main() at testing.cpp:6
6           std::cout << name << "\n";
(gdb) print 1 && name.c_str()
$1 = true
```

Does this problem unique to `c_str()` only? How about other function?

No, this problem is not unique to `c_str()`. It is not even unique to `std::string`. Seems like it happens when we call member function of object inside another object, i.e. `foo.bar.func()`.

Comment: Try to change expression `print 1 && foo->name.c_str()` to `print (1 && foo->name.c_str())`

Comment: @VolAnd Just tried, still not working. Same error message is given. (Attempt to take address...)

Comment: My suggestion is to convert `char *` to `bool` with expression like `print 1 && (0 != foo->name.c_str())`, or read carefully http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC58 (I would start from `set print address off`)

Comment: @VolAnd Just tried `print 1 && (0 != foo->name.c_str())`, still not working with same error message given. Thank you anyway~

Comment: If not a secret, what do you want with `print 1 && foo->name.c_str()`? This is just an experiment of curiosity?

Comment: @VolAnd I was trying to use `break ... if ...` to break at some place if some string variable has certain value. E.g.  `break 14 if foo->name.size() == 5 && $_streq(foo->name.c_str(), "house")`. But gdb give me that error message (Attempt ...) and it break at line 14 (`return 0;`) even though `foo->name` is `"hello"` and not `"house"`.

Comment: gdb is evaluating both the lhs and the rhs of the `&&` expression so it can check whether `&&` is overloaded. It evaluates the rhs in a special "avoid side effects, just return the type of the result" mode, but there's apparently a problem with this kind of expression. `ptype foo->name.c_str()` gets the same error.

Comment: Workaround: use the comma operator. `p $a=foo->name.size(), $b=foo->name.c_str(), $a==5 && $_streq($b, "house")`

Comment: Another workaround: use ternary conditional. `p foo->name.size()==5 ? $_streq(foo->name.c_str(),"house") : 0`